# Pandas data frame excluding rows in a particular range

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame `df` as below.  I am just wondering to exclude rows in a particular column, say `Vader_Sentiment`, which has values in range -0.1 to 0.1 and keep the remaining.

I have tried `df = [df['Vader_Sentiment'] < -0.1 & df['Vader_Sentiment] > 0.1]` but it doesn't seem to work.

```
  Text        Vader_Sentiment       
   A               -0.010   
   B                0.206   
   C                0.003   
   D                -0.089  
   E                0.025
```

Comment: df[(df['Vader_Sentiment'] < -0.1) | (df['Vader_Sentiment'] > 0.1)]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Series.between()`:

```
df.loc[~df.Vader_Sentiment.between(-0.1, 0.1)]

  Text  Vader_Sentiment
1    B            0.206
```

Three things:

- The tilde (~) operator denotes an inverse/complement.
- Make sure you have numeric data.  `df.dtypes` should show float for `Vader_Sentiment`, not "object"
- You can specify an `inclusive` parameter to note if you want intervals to be closed or open